# How to get speed in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-gps

I'm working on an app that provides you with the average speed between two points, but I can't find a way to separate the "location logic" in a separate AsyncTask.
I have to check if you are in one of the two(starting/finishing) points and then add to a list the instant speed and calculate every time the average and display it. I'd like to use the LocationListener, but how I can use it inside an Async task?

In the AsyncTask (i've already all the permission, asked in the main activity):

```
protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        Looper.prepare();
        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Log.d(TAG,"READY");
        Log.d(TAG,locationListener.);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, gpsInterval, 0, locationListener);
        Log.d(TAG,"DONE");
        return "";
    }
```

i see in the logcat the "ready" and the "done" but nothing from myLocationListener

```
public class MyLocationListener  implements LocationListener  {

    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationListener ";

    private MySpeedList speedList= new MySpeedList();


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d(TAG,Float.toString(location.getSpeed()));
        speedList.add(location.getSpeed());
        Log.d(TAG,Float.toString(speedList.getAverageSpeed()));
    }

...
```

Does anyone have suggestions? I'm a student, so I'm a beginner in android, this is my first *"big project"*

Comment: Do you have `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in your manifest? also, you don't have to perform `requestLocationUpdates` in the background since it's not a blocking operation. You can just do it directly on the main thread

Comment: Yes, i have all the permission and they works. I would like to use an asyncTask because i have to "process" all the data came from GPS, but i want also a smooth UI, so....how can i "send" the new data from UI thread to the one that process all the data? with a broadcast, an event? any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute the async task inside the location listener itself and move these lines out to main thread:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
Log.d(TAG,"READY");
Log.d(TAG,locationListener.);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, gpsInterval, 0, locationListener);
Log.d(TAG,"DONE");
return "";
```

And in your listener:

```
public class MyLocationListener  implements LocationListener  {

    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationListener ";

    private MySpeedList speedList= new MySpeedList();


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         if (calculationsTask == null || calculationsTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
             calculationsTask = new CalculationsTask()
             calculationsTask.execute(location);
         } else {
             // buffer pending calculations here or cancel the currently running async task
         }
    }

...
```

**CalculationsTask**

```
 private class CalculationsTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(Location location) {
         // do calculations here
         return speed;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         // this method is executed in UI thread
         // display result to user
     }
 }
```

Here, you can deliver your calculations result through `onPostExecute(...)` method as this method is ran on the main thread. Also note that you cannot execute an async task the second time, so you have to create a new instance every time.

Also, if you want to access `speedList` in your async task, you can make the `CalculationsTask` an inner class of your `MyLocationListener` or just pass it as a parameter.